# How can i post values from android to jsp website

Tags: android, jsp, post, authentication

I am making one android application in this when I login in android app that login details should post to jsp website.How can I store login details into oracle db .......... Please help

Answer (score 0):

Create a Web service which will secure your login details also. [Introduction to Web Services](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijti.html)